# How the value is undefined , when reading from reducer/ store in react redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I am working in react redux. I stored the value in reducer and try to retrieve it. Value is undefined? I am getting the micSessionId from url. In App.js, micSessionId is having value.

```
http://localhost:3000?micSessionId=89e2ff80-c1d7

import * as types from '../lib/store/action';

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(function () {

    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const SessionId = params.get('micSessionId');

    if (SessionId != null && SessionId.length) {
      console.log("saving SessionId: " + SessionId);
      dispatch(
        types.updateData({
          micSessionId: SessionId
        })
      );
    }
 })
}
```

Reducer.js

```
import * as types from './action';

export const initialState = {

    recDetails: {
        name: '',
       country: '',
        city: ''
    },
    micSessionId: ''
}

const Datareducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case types.UPDATE__DATA:

            const output = action.payload;

            if (output.recDetails) {

                state.recDetails = output.recDetails;

            }

            if (output.micSessionId) {

                state.micSessionId = output.micSessionId;

            }

            return {

                ...state,

            }

            break;

        default:

            return state;

    }

}

 

export default Datareducer;
```

```
Action.js

export const UPDATE_DATA = 'UPDATE_DATA';

export const updateData = payload => ({

    type: UPDATE_DATA,

    payload

});
```

Component1.js

```
import * as types from '../../lib/store/action';

const { SessionId } = useSelector(state => state.app.DataReducer.micSessionId);

  const uDispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {

      alert(SessionId);}

SessionId is undefined.....
```

Hi, I am reading the micSessionId from ur parameter in app.js. micSessionId is showing in app.js and then store in reducer. Reading sessionId in component1 is undefined.

Comment: Should `const { SessionId } = useSelector` be `const SessionId = useSelector` ? Your selector seems to target the actual `SessionId` so no destructuring needed there.

Comment: Please help why SessionId is undefined when I am trying to get value in Component1.

Comment: I think Gabriele is correct in the `SessionId` state selection, `state.app.DataReducer.SessionId` ***is*** the `SessionId` value you want, not `SessionId.SessionId`.

Comment: i updated the code. Its still not working. I changed the variable. state.app.DataReducer.SessionId is undefined.

Comment: Can you create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that produces the issue that we could inspect live? You can mock any API request responses, we just need the data you are working with.

Comment: @Drew. Please find the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/late-cache-f7g7ff.   Getting the id from url. Trying to save the sessionId in the reducer in Component1 and trying to use in Component2. Value is not saving somehow. Its saying undefined. Thanks

Comment: I think you pasted your reducer code into the `index.js` file that usually renders the app. Where is the Redux store instantiated and provided? This sandbox seems a little imcomplete.

Comment: I have added the store.js. I need to save sessionId from component1 in reducer. Then I am going to use sessionid in component2.

Comment: And `index.js` that should probably be using `ReactDOM` to render the app?

Comment: thats correct.  please why reducer not save session id

Comment: The index.js file in your sandbox is still your reducer code. The sandbox doesn't run.

Comment: I have updated index.js

Comment: The code in the sandbox you've shared doesn't match the code in your post here. In the sandbox there's only the one reducer, so accessing it will just be `state.sessionId` or `state.sessionDetails`. The `useSelector` usage also has the issue Gabriele called out where you are attempting to destructure a property that doesn't exist on the selected state, e.g. `const { sessionId }  = useSelector((state) => state.sessionId);` should be `const sessionId  = useSelector((state) => state.sessionId);`.

Comment: I tried to use const sessionId  = useSelector((state) => state.sessionId); Its returning null. Please check the sandbox. I have two things in the reducer sessionDetails and sessionId. I want to store both in the reducer so that I can use these later.

Comment: Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-the-value-is-undefined-when-reading-from-reducer-store-in-react-redux-xrepxi) fork.

Comment: @drew, Thanks. Looks like there is an issue in the store.js